# Select list - check on load and on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockitdev/2ZbUS/11/)

Trying to evaluate what option is selected in a select list when the dom is loaded as well as when someone changes the select option.

I thought triggerHandler would cause my function to fire? when the page loads, it should say that value 2 is selected.

```
<select name="select-2" id="select-2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

$(function () {
    function ShowSelected() {
        $('#select-2').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 1) {
                alert('value 1 is selected');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
                alert('value 2 is selected');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
                alert('value 3 is selected');
            }
        });
    }
    $('#select-2').change(ShowSelected).triggerHandler("change");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ShowSelected` is not a event handler, it registers a change event handler.

To make it work change it as shown below

```
$(function () {
    function ShowSelected() {
            if ($(this).val() == 1) {
                alert('value 1 is selected');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
                alert('value 2 is selected');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
                alert('value 3 is selected');
            }
    }
    $('#select-2').change(ShowSelected).triggerHandler("change");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Absr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this - (*Looking at what you have right now*)

```
 ShowSelected(); // <-- bind event to your select-2 in function
 $('#select-2').triggerHandler("change"); // <-- trigger change event
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/g6GWV/

Every time you call `ShowSelected();` you are again binding change event, you should only use your function to show the selected value *as you named it*

Comment: Your second example doesn't optimize anything...I would organize it that way, but it doesn't make it any better. The way to optimize it is to store the result of `$('#select-2')` instead of calling that twice.

Comment: Ok so you mean i just organized it  correctly. not optimized... :O

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/). For example,

```
$('select option:selected') .....
```